# "ajax.open" not working in Windows 8 app

Tags: javascript, ajax, windows-8

I am trying to make a Windows 8 app, but I keep getting "javascript runtime error access denied" errors. The error happens on this page:

```
ajax.open("POST",'save-photo.php',false);
```

Any ideas why and what I should do?

Comment: have you looked at using [xhr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229787.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You see this error because of cross-domain policy. Take a look on standard MSDN documentation about [open method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453349.aspx):

> Security Warning:   Cross-domain, cross-port, and mixed protocol
>   requests are not allowed. The bstrUrl parameter may only specify files
>   in the same domain, using the same port and protocol method, as that
>   from which the page is served.

Because your Windows Store App is serving ms-wwa protocol - I guess this is why you see this error.

If you need to show external web page in your app, please look on this page: [How to link to external web pages (Windows Store apps using JavaScript and HTML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780594.aspx).

If you need to upload file from your Windows Store App, take a look on this page: [Quickstart: Uploading a file (Windows Store apps using JavaScript and HTML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700372.aspx)

Comment: can you get me started on how to work on it. I tried the way MSDN website but still the same error

Comment: @Sadjka, I think it would be good to see a full attempt from you first. The documentation from MSDN should be enough to get you up and running - if you still are having problems, please post more code, since I think the one line on its own is probably not enough to advise you.